# How do I sync/change progress bar progress based on scrollview’s user current scroll value on swift(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, progress-bar

I have **progress bar** within **scrollview** and I need to change that progress bar **value/Color**, when user **start scrolling** ,

Say example progress bar value will be 0 and  background color will be  will be **light gray** in the initial and if user start scrolling means that bar value need be increased gradually(i.e)progress bar background color will be fill with some other **color** based on **Scrolling**.

NOTE:- This is the Screen FYR [Reference design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWCGq.png)

Comment: SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: UIKit and Thanks for the Response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get when the scroll view is scrolling with `scrollViewDidScroll`. Then, you can set the progress view's value based on how much is scrolled.

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        progressView.setProgress(0, animated: false) /// start at 0
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
        
        let percentageOfFullHeight = offset.y / (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height) /// subtract the height of the scroll view, because the bottom of the content won't scroll all the way to the top
        
        progressView.setProgress(Float(percentageOfFullHeight), animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image: scroll to set progress view]

Comment: Ya,It's Working Fine .Thanks

Comment: how about Swift UI?